# Mongoose findById converts empty object to undefined

Tags: mongoose

Mongoose version: `4.13.14`

I have the following data in the db:

```
{
  foo: {}
}
```

with the model:

```
{
  foo: 
    {
      bar: String
    }
 }
```

When I run `model.findById(_id);` I get `foo: undefined` but I was expecting: `foo: {}`

Can anyone explain what is going on?